# Read a file .txt to build a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a filename.txt that contains :

a c

b c

b e

c d

c e

c h

f g

f h

g h

I want to defined a function with two parameters like
     def load_graph (graph, filename)
then to represented it as a dictionary named graph where keys represent vertices and values are list of vertex neighbors

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
          "b" : ["c", "e"],
          "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e", "h"],
          "d" : ["c"],
          "e" : ["b", "c"],
          "f" : ["g", "h"]
          "g" : ["f", "h"]
          "h" : ["c", "f", "g"]
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strongly recommend/suggest to try things self first and post snippet that you have tried and facing problems with as good practice.

considering each line in file have one edge information, you can do something like this:

```
file_data = open("filename.txt")

graph = {}

for line in file_data:
    print line
    fields = line.strip("\n").split(" ")
    key = fields[0]
    value = fields[1]
    if key not in graph:
        graph[key] = [value]
    else:
        graph[key].append(value)

    if value not in graph:
        graph[value] = [key]
    else:
        graph[value].append(key)
```

hope this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to do something with the graph, so you should probably use something like networkx or igraph to read in edge list and construct the graph. If those packages are not available then the following should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def edge_list_to_neighbours(edge_list, directed=False):
    neighbours = dict()
    for source, target in edge_list:
        if not source in neighbours:
            neighbours[source] = [target]
        else:
            neighbours[source] += [target]

    if not directed: # add reverse edge
        for source, target in edge_list:
            if not target in neighbours:
                neighbours[target] = [source]
            else:
                neighbours[target] += [source]

    return neighbours

def read_edge_list(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return [line.strip().split() for line in lines]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    edges = read_edge_list('filename.txt')
    neighbours = edge_list_to_neighbours(edges)
    print neighbours
```